# Knex asking for install sqlite3 but I'm using mysql database

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, node-sqlite3

I'm trying to make a query on my local MySQL database, but when I use the knex it says for me to install the driver of sqlite3 which I don't need because my database is a MySQL.

I tried to install the drive of sqlite3 just to see if it would fix my problem but it just made other errors related to sqlite3 show up, so I just removed the sqlite3 driver.

I already have the driver of MySQL. Below is my code.

Why this error is happening? From what I know it shouldn't be asking me for a sqlite3 driver but just the MySQL as I passed in the configuration for knex.

*** I had already tried to use the driver mysql2 and nothing changed...

```
const knex = require('knex');
require('dotenv').config();

const listUsers = async (req, res) => {

    console.log(process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD);
    //res.send(process.env.DATABASE_USER);

    knex({
        client: 'mysql',
        connection: {
            host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
            user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
            password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME
        }
    })

    knex('users')
        .select('*')
        .then(mysqlres => res.send(mysqlres))
        .catch(mysqlerr => res.send(console.log(mysqlerr)))
}

module.exports = {
    listUsers
};
```

and this is my error :

```
Knex: run
$ npm install sqlite3 --save
Cannot find module 'sqlite3'
Require stack:
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\index.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\knex.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\src\controllers\userController.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\src\routes.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\src\server.js
Error: Cannot find module 'sqlite3'
Require stack:
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\index.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\knex.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\src\controllers\userController.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\src\routes.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\src\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Client_SQLite3._driver (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js:36:12)    
    at Client_SQLite3.initializeDriver (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:232:26)
    at Client_SQLite3.Client (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:70:10)
    at new Client_SQLite3 (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js:18:10)        
    at new Knex (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js:53:28)
    at Knex (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js:17:12)
(node:12648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Knex: run
$ npm install sqlite3 --save
Cannot find module 'sqlite3'
Require stack:
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\index.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\knex.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\src\controllers\userController.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\src\routes.js
- D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\src\server.js
    at Client_SQLite3.initializeDriver (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:236:13)
    at Client_SQLite3.Client (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:70:10)
    at new Client_SQLite3 (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js:18:10)        
    at new Knex (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js:53:28)
    at Knex (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js:17:12)
    at listUsers (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\src\controllers\userController.js:19:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)  
    at next (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\coding\Studies\Moblex\backend-mysql\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)  
(node:12648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12648) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So guys i just figured that i need to make a new instance of Knex when i apply the configuration and that will work ! And the reason that it was asking for the drive sqlite3 before is because knex uses the sqlite3 model. So because i was not making a new instance of the Knex with my own configuration it was using it's default.

so this is my code for the sollution !

```
const listUsers = async (req, res) => {


   const knexapp = knex({
        client: 'mysql2',
        connection: {
            database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
            user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
            password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
        },
        pool: {
            min: 2,
            max: 10
        },
        migrations: {
            tableName: 'knex_migrations'
        }
    })

    knexapp('users').select('*').then(resmsql => res.send(resmsql)).catch(err => res.send(err))
```

Comment: Has anyone else have another answer? I don't think adding an object with the client in every service would be the solution.